# Add Custom Default Places In Google Places AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to make an input with autocomplete use google places API. And this is my code:

```
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "de"
    }
  };
var place = '';

  var locationAutocompleteOneWay = document.getElementById('locationAutocompleteOneWay');
  var autocompleteLocationOneWay = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationAutocompleteOneWay, options);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteLocationOneWay, 'place_changed', function() {
    place = autocompleteLocationOneWay.getPlace();
  });
```

For more customize, I want to add some custom place result when I input in the textbox. Here my code and result:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".pac-container").append('<div id="areasearch" class="pac-item areasearch"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-areas"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>Test place</span> <span>custom place</span></div>');
  }, 500);
```

[image]

But I want when I click on the result, it make my input `locationAutocompleteOneWay` has had a value of the result. But I don't know how to make it. And I want it can apply for multi-input on the page. I use it by jQuery and AngularJS. All solution of Jquery and AngularJS is good for me. Thank in advanced.

Comment: did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that, if you load the custom locations you're adding with attributes that can be used to set the lat/lng (and anything else you need), then you can bind to the mousedown event to assign a custom place object to the autocomplete.

In my script, I have the following snippet adding an item to the autocompletes (this adds to all auto-complete elements on the page):

```
$(".pac-container").append('<div id="areasearch' + i + '" class="pac-item areasearch custom" val="' + PlaceName + '" lat="' + Latitude + '" lng="' + Longitude + '" style="display: none;"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-areas"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>' + PlaceName + '</span> <span>' + LocationName + '</span></div>');
```

Using the classes pac-item and custom,  I then bind as follows:

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("div.pac-item.custom").mousedown(function () {
                setCustomLocation($(this));
            })
        }, 100);
```

And the custom location function is:

```
 setCustomLocation = function (obj) {
        $("#" + currInput).val($(obj).attr("val"));
        var newObj = {};
        newObj["geometry"] = {}
        newObj["geometry"]["location"] = {}
        newObj["geometry"]["location"]["lat"] = function () { return $(obj).attr("lat"); }
        newObj["geometry"]["location"]["lng"] = function () { return $(obj).attr("lng"); }
        currAutocomplete.set("place", newObj);
    }
```

The first line sets the name into the active input field, and the rest sets the place object for the active autocomplete (both variables captured in other events).  The only values I needed for the project was the geometry lat/lng pair, but if you need more, just load it with whatever values you need to retrieve from the parent.